# Can I install squid on regular version of Ubuntu not the server version?

Tags: squid

I am new to all this. I am network professional new to Linux and I am trying to make a proxy server. I have tried installing Squid on Ubuntu 14.04 (the desktop version). I tried installing it but I am greeting this error "unable to locate package squid". The command I used was sudo apt-get install squid3.

I am concerned if Squid needs to be installed on server edition like ISA needs to be installed on server edition of windows.

Comment: you probably need to add the repository linked with squid3. Have you tried searching for this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:

1. ***sudo apt-get update*** to update your package index.
2. ***apt-cache showpkg "squid3"*** to check the package repo index/cache (/var/lib/apt/lists) for the detail availability of the package squid3 in the repos.
3. ***sudo apt-get install "squid3"*** to install the package.

If there is no package shown in the step two please post your repo entries in /etc/apt/sources.list here.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need extra repositories. Squid3 is in main reps. I see it right now. If you really can not install it, you have problems with package installation. Try typing command in manually. Try changing your Apt mirror.
You can install it on any version of Ubuntu, just like pretty anything else.

```
barafu@barafu-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get install squid3
[sudo] password for barafu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libecap2 squid-langpack squid3-common
Suggested packages:
  squidclient squid-cgi squid-purge winbindd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libecap2 squid-langpack squid3 squid3-common
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all three commands heemayl suggested to me, to use but couldn't install the package.

The problem was with the software downloading server. I was using a regional server, and after changing the server to United states I was able to download it.